# Передача структуры в функцию

Tags: c#

Нужно в метод *addHotel* класса *hotel* передать структуру, как мне это сделать в C#?
Или может есть альтернатива?

В C++ это работает. Метод/функция:

```
void addHotel(struct Hotel pony)
{
    ...
}
```

Структура:

```
struct Hotel
{
    ...
};
```

Вызов:

```
Hotel pony;
...
addHotel(pony);
```

Comment: Не понятно, а в чем проблема?

Comment: public void addHotel(struct Hotel pony) - 2 ошибки на C#

Comment: Где вы видите две ошибки?  То есть что здесь за ошибка помимо указания ключевого слова struct?

Comment: struct лишнее, этого я не знал. Всё остальное тут правильное. Ошибки в той строке две из-за одного слова struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

слово `struct` лишнее:

```
void addHotel(Hotel pony)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Аж стыдно стало